# Javascript - avoiding asynchronous race condition when checking object property existence

Tags: javascript, object, asynchronous, properties, race-condition

Whilst JavaScript might not be multi-threaded, it does support asynchronous execution and whilst executions for 2 or more asynchronous bits of code might be on the same thread, the fact that an asynchronous order of events cannot be predicted, makes it possible for a race condition between asynchronous executions to occur.

I am doing an **asynchronous** check for the existence of an object property. Said property will be assigned a large multi-dimensional child object - including child objects arrays, own properties etc.

In the example below, I already know the parent object exists, i.e. I know that `myObject` exists. I want my check to `return true` as soon as ***all the content*** of `myObject['myObjectChildren']` is in place.

To check for the existence of the object property, I do the following:

```
if(myObject.hasOwnProperty('myObjectChildren'))
    return true;
```

The only way that `myObject['myObjectChildren']` gets assigned is in the format, but this assignment is done asynchronously:

```
myObject['myObjectChildren'] = {
          largeChildObject:{
              grandchildren:[
                   {grandchild1:{
                       grandchild1GreatGrandChildren:[
                              grandchild1GreatGrandChild1:{},
                              grandchild1GreatGrandChild2:{}....
                       ]
                   },
                   {grandchild2:{},
                   {grandchild3:{}....
              ]
           }
 };
```

**MY QUESTION:**

My question is, can I safely assume that as soon as `myObject.hasOwnProperty('myObjectChildren') === true`, `myObject['myObjectChildren']` has all the content assigned to it, bearing in mind it is assigned in one go. Is there any circumstance where the check might fail? e.g. on assignment, does the property get instantiated to `'undefined'` first?

Currently, my code is only returning true when all content for it is in place. However, my concern is that I've inadvertently entered into a race condition.

Comment: The answer is "yes" - even with async events JS is still single-threaded, so it's not possible for a javascript function to run "in the middle" of another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the single-threaded nature of javascript execution, your check is correct in all cases when the value is assigned in one synchronous block, as the control flow cannot "jump" to your checking logic while the assignment is executing.